# Store multiple values with a common key but keep the table short in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have three tables user, meeting, and meetingContent.

The users can select different rows from the meetingContent when they create a meeting.

I would like to create a table that records which rows from meetingContent were used for each meeting.

In a previous but similar version of this system there was a table called meeting_meetingContent that held a huge amount of rows as each case when used for each meeting was stored.

I'm not sure if this perhaps the most efficient way, but it seems it could be streamlined somewhat. Are there any altenatives?

Comment: I would say that is the most efficient way of doing it for anything that may require querying in the future. You could just put the values in a delimited list which might be marginally more space efficient but becomes very inefficient to query.

Comment: Kiskstart is right, if you have a n:m relation between meetingContent and meeting_meetingContent, your described way is the right solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try NoSQL like MongoDB. 
Check [here](http://www.mongodb.org/) to see introduction.
in my opinion, maybe NoSQL would be better than SQL. What you do is just save meetings content directly into db, and shows by read content.

Comment: This is an suggestion of a different technique, just like suggesting that someone could use csv files instead of xml. That doesn't answer the question